# pfSense/strongSwan "deleting half open IKE_SA after timeout" - IPSec connection Android 4.4 to pfSense 2.2.1 fails

Tags: vpn, ipsec, pfsense, android

**pfSense** in version 2.2 switched from **Racoon** to **strongSwan**.

Since that change, users can no longer connect to the VPN from Android clients (Type *IPSec Xauth PSK*).

---

**The current configuration on Android is as follows:**

```
|_. Name                       | _[irrelevant]_  |
|_. Type                       | IPSec Auth PSK  |
|_. Server address             | $THE_PFSENSE_IP |
|_. IPSec identifier           | the.identifier  |
|_. IPSec pre-shared key       | 3yZuE7kLFGqOj79hRAqM3vQpPWC7DRlY6ep8hfoVtkZWVqNd8C3W |
|_. DNS search domains         | _[(not used}]_  |
|_. DNS servers                | _[(not used}]_  |
|_. Forwarding routes          | _$LOCAL_IP/32_  |
```

---

**The current configuration on pfSense is as follows:**

- IPSec > Tunnels = *Enable IPSec*

*Phase 1: Mobile Client*

*General information*

```
|_. Disabled              | _[unset]_        |
|_. Key Exchange version  | _V1_             |
|_. Internet Protocol     | _IPv4_           |
|_. Interface             | WAN              |
|_. Description           | _[irrelevant]_   |
```

*Phase 1 proposal (Authentication)*

```
|_. Authentication method | _Mutual PSK + Xauth_ |
|_. Negotiation mode      | _Aggressive_         |
|_. My identifier         | _My IP address       |
|_. Peer identifier       | _Distinguished name_ _the.identifier_ |
|_. Pre-Shared Key        | 3yZuE7kLFGqOj79hRAqM3vQpPWC7DRlY6ep8hfoVtkZWVqNd8C3W |
```

*Phase 1 proposal (Algorithms)*

```
|_. Encryption algorithm  | _AES_ _256 bits_ |
|_. Hash algorithm        | _SHA1_           |
|_. DH key group          | _2 (1024 bit)_   |
|_. Lifetime              | _28800_ seconds  |
```

*Advanced Options*

```
|_. Disable Rekey         | _[unset]_        |
|_. Responder Only        | _[unset]_        |
|_. NAT Traversal         | _Auto_           |
|_. Dead Peer Detection   | _[enabled]_ _10_ seconds, _5_ retries |
```

*Phase 2: Mobile Client*

```
|_. Disabled              | _[unset]_        |
|_. Mode                  | _Tunnel IPv4_    |
|_. Local Network         | *Type:* _Address_ *Address:* _$LOCAL_IP_ *NAT:* _[none/empty]_ |
|_. Description           | _[irrelevant]_   |
```

*Phase 2 proposal (SA/Key Exchange)*

```
|_. Protocol              | _ESP_               |
|_. Encryption algorithms | _AES_ _auto_ *only* |
|_. Hash algorithms       | _SHA1_ *only*       |
|_. PFS key group         | _off_               |
|_. Lifetime              | _3600_ _seconds_    |
```

*Advanced Options*

```
|_. Automatically ping host | _[empty]_         |
```

---

**Log Output on pfSense**

*IPSec Log (startup)*

```
 
Mar 23 02:10:43  ipsec_starter[88815]: Starting weakSwan 5.2.1 IPsec [starter]...
Mar 23 02:10:43  ipsec_starter[88815]: no netkey IPsec stack detected
Mar 23 02:10:43  ipsec_starter[88815]: no KLIPS IPsec stack detected
Mar 23 02:10:43  ipsec_starter[88815]: no known IPsec stack detected, ignoring!
Mar 23 02:10:43  charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.2.1, FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p6, i386)
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[KNL] unable to set UDP_ENCAP: Invalid argument
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[NET] enabling UDP decapsulation for IPv6 on port 4500 failed
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] ipseckey plugin is disabled
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT1_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/a85fc367.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT2_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/5eb84096.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT3_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/16eb0859.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT4_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/e06d03ef.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT5_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/01c1b386.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/acerts'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/crls'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.secrets'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loaded IKE secret for $PFSENSE_IP the.identifier
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loaded IKE secret for %any the.identifier
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] opening triplet file /var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/triplets.dat failed: No such file or directory
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon unbound aes des blowfish rc2 sha1 sha2 md4 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey ipseckey pem openssl fips-prf gmp xcbc cmac hmac curl attr kernel-pfkey kernel-pfroute resolve socket-default stroke smp updown eap-identity eap-sim eap-aka eap-aka-3gpp2 eap-md5 eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap xauth-generic xauth-eap whitelist addrblock unity
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[LIB] unable to load 6 plugin features (5 due to unmet dependencies)
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Mar 23 02:10:44  ipsec_starter[89411]: charon (89559) started after 600 ms
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 06[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'con1'
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 06[CFG] adding virtual IP address pool 192.168.97.0/24
Mar 23 02:10:44  charon: 06[CFG] added configuration 'con1'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] rereading secrets
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] loading secrets from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.secrets'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] loaded IKE secret for $PFSENSE_IP the.identifier
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] loaded IKE secret for %any the.identifier
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] rereading ca certificates from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT1_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/a85fc367.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT2_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/5eb84096.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT3_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/16eb0859.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT4_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/e06d03ef.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] loaded ca certificate "$CERT5_INFO" from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/cacerts/01c1b386.0.crt'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] rereading ocsp signer certificates from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] rereading aa certificates from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] rereading attribute certificates from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/acerts'
Mar 23 02:11:02  charon: 06[CFG] rereading crls from '/var/etc/ipsec/ipsec.d/crls'
```

*IPSec Log (connection)*

```
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[ENC] parsed AGGRESSIVE request 0 [ SA KE No ID V V V V V V V V ]
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02 vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02 vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-00 vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-00 vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  received XAuth vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] received XAuth vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  received Cisco Unity vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] received Cisco Unity vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  received DPD vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] received DPD vendor ID
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE]  $REMOTE_IP is initiating a Aggressive Mode IKE_SA
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[IKE] $REMOTE_IP is initiating a Aggressive Mode IKE_SA
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[CFG] looking for XAuthInitPSK peer configs matching $PFSENSE_IP...$REMOTE_IP[the.identifier]
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[CFG] selected peer config "con1"
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[ENC] generating AGGRESSIVE response 0 [ SA KE No ID NAT-D NAT-D HASH V V V V V ]
Mar 23 02:13:50  charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:13:52  charon: 14[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:13:52  charon: 14[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:13:52  charon: 14[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:13:52  charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:13:54  charon: 14[IKE]  sending retransmit 1 of response message ID 0, seq 1
Mar 23 02:13:54  charon: 14[IKE] sending retransmit 1 of response message ID 0, seq 1
Mar 23 02:13:54  charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:13:55  charon: 14[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:13:55  charon: 14[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:13:55  charon: 14[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:13:55  charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:13:59  charon: 14[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:13:59  charon: 14[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:13:59  charon: 14[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:13:59  charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:01  charon: 14[IKE]  sending retransmit 2 of response message ID 0, seq 1
Mar 23 02:14:01  charon: 14[IKE] sending retransmit 2 of response message ID 0, seq 1
Mar 23 02:14:01  charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:01  charon: 14[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:01  charon: 14[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:01  charon: 14[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:01  charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:05  charon: 16[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:05  charon: 16[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:05  charon: 16[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:05  charon: 16[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:07  charon: 16[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:07  charon: 16[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:07  charon: 16[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:07  charon: 16[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:11  charon: 16[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:11  charon: 16[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:11  charon: 16[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:11  charon: 16[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:13  charon: 16[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:13  charon: 16[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:13  charon: 16[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:13  charon: 16[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:14  charon: 16[IKE]  sending retransmit 3 of response message ID 0, seq 1
Mar 23 02:14:14  charon: 16[IKE] sending retransmit 3 of response message ID 0, seq 1
Mar 23 02:14:14  charon: 16[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:16  charon: 16[NET] received packet: from $REMOTE_IP[500] to $PFSENSE_IP[500] (646 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:16  charon: 16[IKE]  received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:16  charon: 16[IKE] received retransmit of request with ID 0, retransmitting response
Mar 23 02:14:16  charon: 16[NET] sending packet: from $PFSENSE_IP[500] to $REMOTE_IP[500] (432 bytes)
Mar 23 02:14:20  charon: 16[JOB] deleting half open IKE_SA after timeout
```

**What could be the reasons for the connection to fail and how may they be resolved?**

Comment: I just corrected the mentioned shortcomings.

Comment: I've got the same exactly issue and can't find a way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this exact same issue.

As per this [[IKEv1 can't connect from Android's default vpn client](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/255)], there is a bug in the current Android VPN IKEv1 client that happens if aggressive mode is selected and a "IPsec identifier" is used to configure the Android client.

The solution is to **clear** the **"IPsec identifier"** entry from the android client and in **Phase 1 proposal** the negotiation mode should be **Main**.

In my setup the Phase 1 proposal (Authentication) : **Authentication method** is **Mutual PSK + Xauth** and not just Mutual PSK.

Comment: Ah yes, mine says **Mutual PSK + Xauth** as well. I had it changed briefly for testing purpose, so I updated the question accordingly now. Implementing your suggestion I now get `charon: 07[ENC] invalid ID_V1 payload length, decryption failed?` What did you set as **Peer identifier** on the pfSense side?

Comment: That is the root problem. It's only an issue with aggressive mode + PSK. Changing to RSA instead of PSK is the best solution.

Comment: I'll try that. Luis, how did you manage to configure Android to **Main** mode?